# How to use five UITableViews in a single ViewController ,which contains five buttons.first button to first tableview..so on

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to use five tableviews in a single view controller.There are five buttons in the top of view controller.When first button is clicked,show first tableView.While clicking second,show second tableview and so on...

ie consider that the five buttons are five categories.first button is cricket.While clicking first button,show 10 images,based on cricket in first tableview,from the declared array,named cricketImages.Second category button is Football....while clicking second button show FootballImages array's data in second tableview....Pls help...

Comment: If you going to using 5 UITableView in a single view controller then it very bad design. Use 5 datasource for single tableview and reload your tableview according to button and respective data.

Comment: Why not 1 table with sections...

Comment: The other thing you ought look at (besides these other two wise suggestions..) if you're really committed to this is UIPickerView, which is a bunch of parallel tables already done for you.

Comment: thank u all for your reply....trying to use multiple datasource for single tableview..

Answer (score 1):

you use only one table with different-2 Data Array and based on button click you change data array and reload table